# What is the standard method for implementing navigation menus in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create navigation through the use of a menu in my app, but I'm not sure how it should be done. I currently have a system set out like this:

```
ContainerViewController
|
+---CenterNavigationController
        |
        +---ViewControllerA [i.e. the root view controller which will be changed]
        |
        +---MenuViewController [pushed to navigation stack on btn press]
```

and when a item in the menu is pressed to load another view controller, MenuViewController calls a delegate method in the ContainerViewController which replaces the NavigationController with a new one with a different root

```
let newVC = ViewControllerB()
CenterNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newVC)
```

However this looks janky, both in the code and in the aesthetics of the app.

I'm not sure how to do this properly. I'm wanting the menu to be overlayed onto the current view, and have the ability to click 'back' in the menu to go back to what was showing on screen before the menuVC was loaded. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do all correct. If navigation animation isn't good, then improve it. You can show menu animated from the left side and reload CenterNavigationController without animation. As for transparence, then just change the color of the main view of the menu view controller to semitransparent. The first subview that contains all menu items should be non-transparent and have lower width and sticked to the left side. That's it.

I think you should not push menu view controller into the navigation stack. Just load it right into the UINavigationView controller.

You can check `loadViewController` (line 251) method here https://gitlab.com/seriyvolk83/SwiftEx/blob/master/Source/UIExtensions.swift

It loads view controller into another view controller in a given bounds. To remove it later (close menu) you can use `remove()` (see line 321)

Answer (score 0):

Hamburger menu is antipattern on iOS, I suggest using UITabBarController. If someone is holding a gun to your head and forcing you to put a hamburger menu in your app then use something like this: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Comment: Useful information, but now what I wanted to know! Appreciated though - I'll have a look through the code